# change a query to an update

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have the following query:

```
SELECT        UsersAccountLink.UserId, Customer.Account.AccountNumber, Web.Customer.Name, Web.Customer.Street, UsersAccountLink.AccountId
FROM            UsersAccountLink INNER JOIN
                         Web.Customer ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Web.Customer.AccountId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Customer.Account ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Customer.Account.AccountId
WHERE        (Customer.Account.AccountNumber IS NULL)
Order by Name
```

I need to change the select to and update. I need the UsersAccountLink.UserId to be set to an empty guid if Customer.Account.AcountNumber IS NULL.

I doubt I have this right so here is what I came up with:

```
UPDATE
    UsersAccountLink
SET
    UsersAccountLink.AccountId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
FROM            
    UsersAccountLink 
INNER JOIN
    Web.Customer ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Web.Customer.AccountId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Customer.Account ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Customer.Account.AccountId
WHERE        
    (Customer.Account.AccountNumber IS NULL)
```

I based that off this post [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
    Table.col2 = other_table.col2
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN
    other_table
ON
    Table.id = other_table.id
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to test run a query, such as an update or delete, before actually running it?
2. Did I convert it to an update correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Test a code without running it? I don't know.. Can't you make a copy of the database for testing purposes and run against it?

Comment: Run without actually updating or deleting records. The database is huge and located on a hosted server. I would take quite a while to pull down and run it locally. That is, if I were given permissions to pull the whole database. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
This is what you can do to test

insert a select statment here to view the record(s) before the insert
BEgin tran
UPDATE
    UsersAccountLink
SET
    UsersAccountLink.AccountId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
FROM            
    UsersAccountLink 
INNER JOIN
    Web.Customer ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Web.Customer.AccountId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Customer.Account ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Customer.Account.AccountId
WHERE        
    (Customer.Account.AccountNumber IS NULL)

insert a select statment here to view the record(s) after the insert
Rollback tran
```

It is still best to do that on dev not prod.  In the particular case you have, I would want to to also test what happens if this is run later on a differnt record. Or at least check to make sure you don't have a unique index on accountid.

I also like to do this:

```
UPDATE
    UsersAccountLink
SET
    UsersAccountLink.AccountId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
--SELECT * (or you can specify columns you specifically want to see)

FROM            
    UsersAccountLink 
INNER JOIN
    Web.Customer ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Web.Customer.AccountId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Customer.Account ON UsersAccountLink.AccountId = Customer.Account.AccountId
WHERE        
    (Customer.Account.AccountNumber IS NULL)
```

This allow you to easily check the by running the commented select. It aslo makes it easy to change a select to an update by writing the select, then putting the update info on top of it and commenting everything in the select before the FROM statmenet.

Comment: I was just finishing comment to use transactions :)

Comment: You would have to test on your data, but it looks ok to me. However, I am not familar with your database struture or the meaning of your data, so I cannot say if it is correct except that the syntax (the least important part of a query) seems to be fine.